# Is there a RichTextBox equivalent to a ListBox.ItemTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there a RichTextBox equivalent to a ListBox.ItemTemplate?

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Col0"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Col1"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Col2"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding tabType}"/>
      <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding tabPhone}"/>
      <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding tabLast}"/>
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
```

This ListBox.ItemTemplate coupled with a class (tabType { get; set; }) organizes the display into columns.

---

Edited 50 minutes later.

The above ListBox code results in three columns. The goal is to have a RichTextBox with three columns.

Comment: Can you specify what you are looking for? The `ItemTemplate` of a `ListBox` specifies how each item in the list box is going to be displayed. What would the equivalent effect in a `RichTextBox` be, specify how each character is displayed?

Comment: Maybe try posting an image illustrating the effect you are after, and also explain why you seem to be set on using a **RichTextBox** control for this.

Answer (score 0):

You use a FlowDocument inside RichTextBox and use Table control to display the table or grid like data. Refer the below code.

```
 <RichTextBox Margin="10">
        <FlowDocument>
            <Table>                   
                <Table.Columns>
                    <TableColumn />
                    <TableColumn />
                    <TableColumn />
                </Table.Columns>                   
                <TableRowGroup>                      
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>                                
                            <Paragraph>Cell at Row 1 Column 1</Paragraph>
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell>
                            <Paragraph>Cell at Row 1 Column 2</Paragraph>
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell>
                            <Paragraph>Cell at Row 1 Column 3</Paragraph>
                        </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>
                            <Paragraph>Cell at Row 2 Column 1</Paragraph>
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell>
                            <Paragraph>Cell at Row 2 Column 2</Paragraph>
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell>
                            <Paragraph>Cell at Row 2 Column 3</Paragraph>
                        </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableRowGroup>
            </Table>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
```

In LisBox we can bind to collection but here i am not sure how to achieve the same in RichTextBox and table.